# Rally's .Net rest API

Tags: rest, api, rally

We are having issue when we set the pagesize, it seems like it is hardcoded to 200.
Is it possible to change the pagesize to 100o or 2000? We tried setting the limit, did not work. It always returned the Queryresult.results was 200.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Vasanthi

Answer (score 0):

Unforunately, this seems to be a limitation with this specific toolkit: it has the page size max defined in code as 200: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/blob/d6c2f58781eddf986a17d7b016ac397921ac39ce/Rally.RestApi/Request.cs#L78

That's unfortunate, because the max page size was actually increased to 2000 in wsapi a couple years ago.

I created an issue to track this here: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/issues/40

Your best workaround in the meantime is probably to fork this repo, make the change and just build the library from source since I'm not sure in what sort of timeframe we'll be able to get this fixed on our end.  We definitely also accept pull requests if you'd like to contribute back!

But this will require a new release of the toolkit to properly address for sure.